# Why does the animation stop one secend after last frame in three.js?

Tags: animation, three.js

I'm a three.js beginger, I want to run the animation in three.js, I found a problem.

The 1st gif is animation in blender, and the 2nd gif is animation in three.js. Why does the animation in three.js stoped after last frame? How to make the animation smoothly?

Below is the code:

```
var mixers = [];
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

loader.load('models/gltf/shuilunji0820.glb', function (gltf) {
    gltf.scene.position.y = 90;

    scene.add(gltf.scene);

    render();

    var mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene.children[2]);

    mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[1]).setDuration(2).play();
    mixers.push(mixer);
});

var time;
var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    
    // repeat
    for (var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++) {
        mixers[i].update(delta);
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
animate();
```

[image: pic in blender]

[image: pic in three.js]

Comment: Do you mind removing the call of `setDuration()`?

Comment: I've tried, it was not working.`mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[1]).play();`